# fe_sendauth: no password supplied when using rails with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
volumes:
  - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  environment:
    - PGHOST=db
    - PGUSER=postgres
  volumes:
    - .:/docker
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - db
```

I can successfully connect to psql

```
psql postgres postgres
```

But when I try to run rake db:create I am getting the following error

```
Couldn't create 'docker_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted! ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `PGPASSWORD` in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

POSTGRES_PASSWORD in docker-compose and database.yml.
I hope you are running a command inside a docker container or against running docker
`docker-compose run web rake db:create` 
`docker exec -it {container_id} /bin/bash`

try this also `POSTGRES_DB: docker_development`